# .NET login endpoint responses differ in test and live environments

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis

We have our app written in .NET framework 4.6.1. I am trying to get the Login endpoint to send a given JSON Response if login fails.

We have 2 environments setup on the same machine and the endpoints responds differently on both.

The first one returns the appropriate object as follows

```
{ "Success": false, 
  "Message": "User Name or Password is incorrect, please try again.", 
  "RedirectLink": null,
  "ErrorType": 18, 
  "Payload": null
 }
```

The second environment, however, returns a HTML page instead of the JSON object as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <title>403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        <!--
        body {
            margin: 0;
            font-size: .7em;
            font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            background: #EEEEEE;
        }

        fieldset {
            padding: 0 15px 10px 15px;
        }

        h1 {
            font-size: 2.4em;
            margin: 0;
            color: #FFF;
        }

        h2 {
            font-size: 1.7em;
            margin: 0;
            color: #CC0000;
        }

        h3 {
            font-size: 1.2em;
            margin: 10px 0 0 0;
            color: #000000;
        }

        #header {
            width: 96%;
            margin: 0 0 0 0;
            padding: 6px 2% 6px 2%;
            font-family: "trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;
            color: #FFF;
            background-color: #555555;
        }

        #content {
            margin: 0 0 0 2%;
            position: relative;
        }

        .content-container {
            background: #FFF;
            width: 96%;
            margin-top: 8px;
            padding: 10px;
            position: relative;
        }
        -->
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="header">
        <h1>Server Error</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <div class="content-container">
            <fieldset>
                <h2>403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.</h2>
                <h3>You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.
                </h3>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I tried comparing the web.config files for the App but couldn't find any differences except the second one has `<customErrors off />` while the first one does not. Changing it did not fix the solution.

To summarize the problem:
The endpoint responds with a JSON object in test environment (like it is supposed to) but in production it responds with a HTML page (instead of JSON object).

What could cause this problem ? and how do I fix it ?

Thanks.

Comment: you have different settings for debug and release ? You didn't provide any information about your setup and code, project file or anything

Comment: web.config doesn't contain all settings for iis, in addition to applicationHost file, so please post details about your problem.

Answer (score 1):

`403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.`

Here, there is issue in access. check the access of user/iis user on the folder of that application which giving problem.

**Compare access of user on folder of both application. you will find differences**

Let me know if you are still facing same problem.

Comment: Hi, it is supposed to show ```403 - Forbidden``` because I am passing incorrect login details. This is being done on purpose for testing the API response on incorrect login.

The issue is that both environments send response in different formats. Instead of JSON object like in the example showed above, the production environment is  returning HTML code.

Comment: you should improve your question and give more details

Comment: I have updated my question and added a problem summary towards the end of it.

Comment: Predeep is right, there is an authentication issue somewhere. What you are using oAuh? Which account you use in debug, which in release ? is there a different ? you have your own authentication server? then debug there why not authenticated

Comment: You provided to less information (no code at least) to solve this issue from our point of view. You have to work on this